# javascript lotto task for loop+match

Tags: javascript, for-loop, match

I´m stuck in this task, is a lotto generation, and I have to use a for loop, a match and AND, but I don´t know where use the AND compound, and the code that I have wrote is not working, any help?

**Use a For loop to step through each position in the winning numbers array and
to compare the customer number to each number the array contains.
To complete this, you will need to set up the following.
1. A counter variable (e.g. i) for the loop.
2. A boolean variable (e.g. match) to flag if a match has been found or not.
3. A compound AND condition that allows the loop to continue to iterate only
if a match is not found, and, the end of the array has not been reached.
4. An if statement nested inside the For loop which checks the customer
number against each winning number in the array, each time the loop
iterates, and sets the boolean, match, to true if a match is found.**

This is my code

```
var customerNumbers = prompt ("Please enter your number");
var winningNumbers = ['12','17','24','37','38','43'];
var match = false;

//These are the messages that will be show

var winningMessage = "This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n" + winningNumbers + "\n";
var customerMessage = "The Customer's Number is:\n" + customerNumbers + "\n";
var winnerMessage = "We have a match and a winner";
var notWinnerMessage = "Sorry you are not a winner this week";

/* Adding a for loop with a conditional and a boolean
*/

for (i=0; i<winningNumbers.length; i++) {
    if (!match){
        alert( winningMessage + customerMessage + notWinnerMessage);
    }

        else {
            alert( winningMessage + customerMessage + winnerMessage);
        }
}
```

Many thanks

Comment: Your logic is wrong. Do a loop and check if the same index on winning numbers is equal to their numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (if customerNumbers are comma separated):

```
var customerNumbers = prompt("Please enter your number").split(/\s*,\s*/);
var winningNumbers = ['12','17','24','37','38','43'];
var match = true;

//These are the messages that will be show

var winningMessage = "This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n" + winningNumbers + "\n";
var customerMessage = "The Customer's Number is:\n" + customerNumbers + "\n";
var winnerMessage = "We have a match and a winner";
var notWinnerMessage = "Sorry you are not a winner this week";

/* Adding a for loop with a conditional and a boolean
*/

for (i=0; i<winningNumbers.length; i++) {
   if (customerNumbers.indexOf(winningNumbers[i]) === -1) {
       match = false;
       break;
   }
}
if (!match){
   alert( winningMessage + customerMessage + notWinnerMessage);
} else {
   alert( winningMessage + customerMessage + winnerMessage);
}
```